# Asp.Net 5 core 1.0 Incompatible / Template not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnvm, asp.net5

I am stumped on this one, I am trying to build my first core 1.0 application and for some reason I cannot get the core 1.0 templates to load correctly both in a new solution and when I try to open a sample core 1.0 solution.  I currently have Microsoft ASP.Net 5 RC1 Update 1 installed. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition Update 2 with pretty much all the features installed.  I have tried repairing visual studio, and also tried reinstalling visual studio with just Visual Studio Community Edition.  When I try to add an ASP.Net 5 Core 1.0 project to a .Net solution I get the following error:

[image: Error adding project]

When I try to open a solution with an ASP.Net 5 project inside of it I get the following error: 
[image: Error Opening Solution]

Finally, if I try to remove the project and re-add it through add existing project I get 2 error messages:

[image: Error Re-adding 1]
[image: Error Re-adding 2]

I have been stumped on this for the past 2 days, please help!  Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just to prove I have the correct binaries installed:
[image]

Comment: are you sure you have the latest asp.net rc1 bits from https://get.asp.net/ ? Install it from there if you have not recently

Comment: I am positive I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling those bits multiple times.  I have also tried repairing.

Comment: have you tried it with a brand new solution, or creating a new web app and let it create the solution when it creates the project to see if that works

Comment: Yeah I tried that and I get the first error message above, templates not found.  At this point I have also tried reinstalling visual studio templates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems that Asp.Net 5 / Core 1.0 does not support a Visual Studio install to a drive other than the C:/ drive.  I had it installed on the D:/ drive and because of this it was not finding the templates from the Asp.Net 5 install.  I had to do a full Visual Studio clean uninstall using  /uninstall /force, then I had to utilize the  /CustomInstallPath  to reinstall visual studio to the C:/ drive.